# How to set a EditText listener for specific numbers?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, keyword, toast

I want a listener for my `EditText` field in a application which should listen for a specific row of numbers I think of.

For example:
If users type in the numbers "12345" and press the button, a `toast` message has to show up. If users type in other numbers than "12345", the `button` has to run his main function.

I want it as a litte easter egg inside my application.

Comment: editText.getText().equals("12345") ????

Comment: But how to run a specific action than?

Comment: Just maintain a list of numbers or text that are allowed and check against it in the onClick listener of the button.Just put an if loop and run the specific action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditText allows you to add a TextWatcher view addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher):

Lets assume you have:

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
```

We can then add a TextWatcher to it:

```
// Add the TextChangeListener which is a TextWatcher
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             //... For listening to text on the fly
             if(s.toString().equals("12345")){
                  Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Some message" Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               //... for a callback after text is changed
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ellaborating on @Kristo1990 's answer:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
```

Then on your button press:

```
if (editText.getText().toString().equals("12345")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message is 12345", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    someOtherMethod();
}
```

Safer (and lighter) then a unecessary `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a onTextChanged Listener

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if(mEditText.getText().toString().equals("12345"))
               //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an If statement to check the value of the editText, like:

```
 if(editText.getText().equals("12345"))
 {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message is 12345",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Any of the answers here would work actually, thank you anyway :) !

Comment: Yours is way cleaner. Creating a TextWatcher is prone to a lot of ANRs, with a simple method that gets the text is more "safe", but I would improve it. editText.getText().toString() just to be safe ;)

Comment: Well said, for the `toString()` method . I won't say much about textWatcher because I have not read anything about it yet. But, you know how it goes for a lot of programmers, if it works it works.